# Rails: Compare old value and new value during validation for edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a custom validation function that will not allow a field to be saved empty/nil only if the current field is not empty in the database. How can I access the database value (old value) in the validation function? I can access the new value using self.name_of_field.

This is what I have right now

```
validate :image_remote_url_change
  def image_remote_url_change
    if self.image_remote_url.blank? and self.image_remote_url_changed?
      errors.add(:field, "can't be blank once set")
      return false
    end
  end
```

Right now if I try to edit an existing object, it won't accept a new value of empty but when creating a new object it will say "can't be blank once set" even though the old value was never set.

Answer (score 11):

You can take advantage of [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html). In your custom validation function you can check if field is blank and if it has changed:

```
validate :custom_validation_function

def custom_validation_function
  if self.field.blank? and self.field_changed?
      errors.add(:field, "can't be blank once set")
      return false
  end
end
```

Comment: +1. Schneems, from Heroku, has a [brief article](http://schneems.com/post/28425724540/get-previously-saved-changes-in-rails) discussing the previous_changes method, which might help you out too

Comment: Doesn't this only work though if the object actually changed? as in it was saved successfully. I'm just doing this on a validation step

Comment: It doesn't work. On the edit it seemed to be working but on the new action I can't create with the empty field (there should be no old value so should work). Ill update the question with my code

Comment: it's been a long time, but maybe it will help someone else - just add  'and !new_record?' to the if statement to make sure that this code runs only for already saved objects

Comment: nowadays, rather than checking for `!new_record?`, you can tell the validation to only be run on updates (not on creates) with the `:on` option, e.g. `validate :custom_validation_function, on: :update` -- see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on